# sequelize ignore "save()" method on JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am trying to take benefits of model instance methods, as stated in the [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#taking-advantage-of-models-being-classes). So I defined `User` class as following:

```
class User extends Model {
    addRole(role){
        let roles = this. roles;
        roles[role] = true;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.save();
    }

    removeRole (role) {
        let roles = this.roles;
        delete roles[role];
        this.save();
    }
    
    hasRole (role){
        return this.roles[role] != null;
    }
}


User.init({
// some attributes
,
roles:{
  type: DataTypes.JSON,
  allowNull: false,
}
}, { sequelize});
```

I expected to use methods `addRole()`, `removeRole()` and `hasRole()` in any `User` instance.

The problem that all the methods can't save their changes to database. (Can read only!)

```
// example 
let user = null; 
// get the first user to test.
User.findAll() 
    .then(users =>{
          user = users[0];
          user.addRole("admin");
          console.log(user.roles); // {admin: true} 
          user.save();
          // However the changes don't appear in the database.
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I had found the answer.
For some reasons, `sequelise` can't detect the changes of the json object properly. As `sequelise` is optimised internally to ignore call to `model.save()` if there is no changes of the model. So, sequelize randomly ignore the `save` method.

This behavior had no relation with instance method as I believed when I face this problem first time.

To get out of this problem, I had to use :

```
 user.addRole("admin");
 user.changed("roles", true); // <<<< look at this;
 console.log(user.roles); // {admin: true} 
 user.save();
```

> Please note that this function will return false when a property from a nested (for example JSON) property was edited manually, you must call changed('key', true) manually in these cases. Writing an entirely new object (eg. deep cloned) will be detected.

> Example:

```
const mdl = await MyModel.findOne();
mdl.myJsonField.a = 1;
console.log(mdl.changed()) => false
mdl.save(); // this will not save anything
mdl.changed('myJsonField', true);
console.log(mdl.changed()) => ['myJsonField']
mdl.save(); // will save
```

[changed method usage](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-changed)